# Send array data to email through Laravel Mailable

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, forms

I have the following lines for the create.blade.php (My Form)

```
<form action="/contact" method="POST">
    <div class="form-control">

<fieldset>
    <legend><span class="number">1</span> Personal Information</legend>


        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name *" value="{{old('name') }}">
        <div>{{ $errors->first('name') }} </div>

        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Phone *" value="{{old("email") }}">
        <div>{{ $errors->first('email') }} </div>

        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone *" value="{{old('phone') }}">
        <div>{{ $errors->first('phone') }} </div>   
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10">{{old('message') }} 
      </textarea>
        <div>{{ $errors->first('message') }} </div>

<?php
$countries = array('India' => 'India',
        'Pakistan' => 'Pakistan',
        'Bosnia' => 'Bosnia',
        'Andorra' => 'Andora',
        'Haiti' => 'Haiti',
        'Australia' => 'Australia',
        'Maldives' => 'Maldives'
        );
?>

<label for="message">Country</label>

<select name="country">
    @foreach ($countries as $country)
        <option value="{{ $country }}" @if(old('country') == $country) selected="selected" @endif>{{ 
$country }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
@csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
</div>
</form>
```

For my contact-form.blade.php (Mailable) I have the followig. This is supposed to show the submitted data in the email that I receive. The problem is I get all the data in input fields (Name, Number Email) BUT I dont get the selected country data. The problem most probably lies in the following lines.

```
 @component('mail::message')

#Requested Information

<strong>Name</strong> {{ $data['name'] }}
<strong>Email</strong> {{ $data['email'] }}

<strong>Message</strong> {{ $data['message'] }}

<strong>Country</strong> {{ $data['$country'] }}

@endcomponent
```

Comment: What are you getting in `$data['$country']`? Have you tried removing the $?

Comment: I get an error even after removing this. 

ErrorException {#272 ▶}

Comment: What is the output of `$data`? And why can't you use Request? Then you can simply get the selected country with `$request->country`...

Comment: Im making a drop down list of countries. The user selects a country in the form. Once I get the mail, the selected country must appear in my inbox.
See in the question I have put the list of countries as an array. The expected output is in my Mailtrap I must get the message with the selected country. I only get the other fields like name, email and phone .

Comment: The expected output is the name of the selected country (from drop down list) must appear on the Markdown mail I get to mailtrap. The issues is only with drop down list . Other inputs are working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The correct is `$data['country']` not `$data['$country']`.

Comment: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined index: country (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\resources\views\emails\contact\contact-form.blade.php)

Comment: This $data is a variable $country. UNLIKE the @data "name" and "email". The problem is I cannot send this selected country (from dropdown) does not appear in the Markdown mail. All is set except sending this selected input from drop down to Markdown mail. The Name and Email input gets into inbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the following code

```
 $data=array(
        'Name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'country'=>$request->country,
        'phone'=> $rwquest->phone,
    );

    Mail::send('here your email filename', $data, function($message)  {
        $message->subject('');   //subject of email
        $message->from();   // sender email address
        $message->to();   //receiver email
    });
```

Comment: The name and email as not in array (just a text input field)
The countries list is the array.
Heres my codes for the Markdown mail file

@component('mail::message')

#Quotation Request

<strong>Name</strong> {{ $data['name'] }}
<strong>Email</strong> {{ $data['email'] }}
<strong>Phone</strong> {{ $data['phone'] }}
<strong>Message</strong>{{ $data['message'] }}
<strong>Country</strong> XXXXXX

@endcomponent

Need the part XXXXX to be filled correctly

Answer (score 0):

I have inserted the following line

```
$countries = $_POST['country'];
```

Now it looks like this

```
<select>
    $countries = $_POST['country'];

@foreach ($countries as $country)
<option value="{{ $country }}" name="country"

@if(old('country') == $country) selected="selected" 
@endif>

{{ $country }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Also the following line in my mailmake

```
Country {{ $data['country'] }}
```

I get the error undefined index:country